# A grid gallery view using css only, with same width different height

Tags: php, html, css

i am working on a grid view for image gallery

this is what i did so far but there are still vertical spaces between some of the photos
CSS:

```
#container{
    background-color:transparent;
    top: 60px;
    left:8%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid ;
    width: 82.19%;
    position:absolute; 
    outline: 0;
}

.box {
    background-color:#3e3e3e;
    border:1px solid #bebebe;
    margin: 6px 3.5px;
    width:362px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border-radius:3.6px;
}
.box:nth-child(2n + 0) {
    float: right;
}
```

how i am applying it:

```
<div id='container'>
<?php

(some php & mysql here)

echo "<div class='box'><img src='pictures/$image' width='360' ></div>";
</div>

?>
```

i can't figure out the proper css to create a grid view with no extra vertical spaces.

images have varying heights fixed width, the space i m talking is that space which is not letting grid structure to form properly the vertical distance b/w some photos is alot more than it should be

Is there anybody who can help me?

NOTE: Don't suggest any jquery plugins i want to use pure css

Comment: Is the height of the images variable? The height difference is that vertical space you are talking about?

Comment: Are all the images with the same height?

Comment: You could try [multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts). Of course that would only allow a fixed number or width of columns (media queries might help) and the order of the pictures might be counterintuitive for the user. [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/xuyinetusazu/1/edit)

Comment: If you want to arrange your photos in a masonry like fashion but without using JS, you only have one solution left: [CSS flexbox](http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox). However, the items have to be arranged in a column-like order.

Comment: Have a look at [foundation's block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html)

Comment: still not working help!